# Convert JavaScript RegEx to C# RegEx for email validation

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

How could I convert the following javascript regex into c# regex?

```
 function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
               var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
               return pattern.test(emailAddress);
 }
```

Simply passing the string into a C# Regex class and returning a Match doesn't work. I think the string needs to be edited, but I'm not a Regex expert.

Comment: I'd hate to have to debug that regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are working with C#, you should be able to validate email addresses using the [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) class. You can use it like this:

```
public bool IsValidEmailAddress(string emailAddress)
{
    try
    {
        MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailAddress);
        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Sometimes you can go without regexes, especially if you're not an expert.

Comment: how comprehensive is this? my concern is that it won't be as detailed so the server side will not be as robust. sorry, i'm just trying to make sure my email validation system is not weak.

Comment: I thought you wanted to validate email addresses using C# sorry. If it's not the case, I think you should edit your question to explain what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I'm trying to validate email addresses on both the client and the server, so I'm using the javascript code for client side validation.

Answer (score 1):

@Mark13426: It seems it's due to the unicode & octal notation beig used in there.

Instead, you can definitely go for this Regex:

```
^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$
```

For more info, refer:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx